# How to apply fubinis theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a double integral $\int_{\varepsilon}^r\int_{B(0,s)}f(y)dyds$. How to get rid of the $s$ in the ball $B(0,s)$ so that i can apply the fubinis theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's give it a try. So I think you can just apply Fubini. Let us assume $B(0,s) \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ for $ \epsilon < s < r$. Then you can write

$$ \int_{\epsilon}^r \int_{B(0,s)} f(y) dy ds = \int_{\epsilon}^r \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) \mathbb{1}_{B(0,s)}(y) dy ds = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y) \int_{\epsilon}^r \mathbb{1}_{B(0,s)}(y) ds dy  $$

Now the next step would be to reformulate the indicator function $ \mathbb{1}_{B(0,s)} $ into a function that takes $s$ as an argument instead of $y$ and then calculate the first integral.

Comment: i think you can write the integral as $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} 1_{\max\{|y|,\varepsilon\} < s <  r}(s,y)dyds$

Comment: and after fubini we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\max\{|y|,\varepsilon\}}^{r} 1_{B(0,r)}(y)dsdy$

Comment: and hence $\int_{B(0,r)}\int_{\max\{|y|,\varepsilon\}}^{r}dsdy$